# Error when calling a function from inside another function in C

Tags: c

I have to create a function which simplifies fractions. It'd be great if I could call another function from inside the function, to find the GCD easily.

My code is:

```
int mcd(int n1, int n2){
    int mcd = 1;
    for(int i = 2; i <= n1 && i <= n2; ++i){
        if(n1 % i == 0 && n2 % i == 0){
            mcd = i;
        }
    }
    return mcd;
}

int reduir(fraccio* sol){
    int a, b, mcd;
    a = sol->num;
    b = sol->den;
    mcd = mcd(a, b);
    sol->num = sol->num / mcd;
    sol->den = sol->den / mcd;

    if (sol->num < 0) {
        sol->signe = '-';
        sol->num = sol->num * -1;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I get a compilation error on the line

```
    mcd = mcd(a, b);
```

> Called object type `int` is not a function or function pointer

What did I do wrong, and how do I fix it?

Comment: Please post the code here.

Comment: Well, as __text__.

Comment: Best would be if you can write the code over here instead of linking or posting image.

Comment: _Questions seeking debugging help (why isn't this code working?) must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a [mcve]._

Comment: ...and the error message?

Comment: @coderredoc go ahead, undelete the answer now.

Comment: @SouravGhosh.: But I guess question will be deleted soon.

Comment: The error message is in the picture above the code...

Comment: @coderredoc, well, there's that. that's why it's not a good idea to invest your effort in answering these questions. Just my two cents. :)

Comment: @Adria OK, and you think text in images are _searchable_?

Comment: Just rename the `mcd` function and call it. Functions in C have global namespace (unless declared `static` which makes then visible within the file). Using a variable with the same name as a function inside a function hides the function (with the same name as the variable). Hence, your compiler thinks `mcd` is the local `int` and complains that you are trying to use an `int` as a function.

Comment: Come on... this is a new user asking a valid question... :) and already 7 downvotes...

Comment: @Adria general hint for next time you ask a question: Never post pictures of text but post the text and get familiar with [stackoverflow's mark down formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting), it's not difficult.

Comment: Better than renaming the function: rename your `int mcd;` local variable to a name that doesn't shadow the `mcd()` function.  Some other hints: you'll want to normalise the signs *before* the MCD reduction; you can use unary `-` instead of multiplying by `-1`; there are more efficient implementations of `mcd()` - look up **Euclid's Algorithm**.

Answer (score 2):

You are redeclaring `mcd` as `int`. That is where the problem is. It is shadowing the globally declared function `mcd()`. Now when you call it you are basically trying to use an `int` variable in the form of function name. Compiler complains that.